# How to use Web Share API on Website for web-view?

Tags: android, android-webview

I already created a web-view android app from my website.
I added Web Share API code to my website to load share button on android browser (It works fine) but when I visit my website through the android app, share button doesn't work (Nothing happens when I press the button).
Any idea to solve the problem? Is it possible?

Web Share API Code

```
<button id="btn-share">Share</button>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if(!navigator.share) {
      document.querySelector('.share-container').innerHTML = 'Web Share API not supported in this browser';
      return;
    }

    document.getElementById('btn-share').addEventListener('click', function() {
      navigator.share({
        title: 'Check out this web share API demo',
        text: 'Its really cool',
        url: 'https://mobiforge.github.io/web-share-api.html',
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.share API not supports in WebView. You can use it only in mobile browsers except Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Web share is not yet support for browser but you can use fall back method.

```
if (navigator.share) { 
   navigator.share({ 
      title: 'harish tech', 
      text: 'Check out harishtech.com.', 
      url: 'https://harishtech.com', }) 
   .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
   .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing',       error)); 
}else{ 
// Your fall back code here
 }
```

For more info check out the link [share like native app](https://harishtech.com/articles/sharing-at-next-level.html)